# C++: Getline stops reading at first whitespace

Tags: c++, string, vector, getline

Basically my issue is that I'm trying to read in data from a .txt file that's full of numbers and comments and store each line into a string vector, but my getline function stops reading at the first whitespace character so a comment like (* comment *) gets broken up into

```
str[0] = "(*";
str[1] = "comment";
str[2] = "*)";
```

This is what my codeblock for the getline function looks like:

```
int main() {
string line;
string fileName;
cout << "Enter the name of the file to be read: ";
cin >> fileName;

ifstream inFile{fileName};

istream_iterator<string> infile_begin {inFile};
istream_iterator<string> eof{};
vector<string> data {infile_begin, eof};
while (getline(inFile, line))
{
    data.push_back(line);
}
```

And this is what the .txt file looks like:

```
101481
10974
1013
(* comment *) 0
28292
35040
35372
0000
7155
7284
96110
26175
```

I can't figure out why it's not reading the whole line.

Answer (score 5):

This is for the very simple reason that your code is not using `std::getline` to read the input file.

If you look at your code very carefully, you will see that before you even get to that point, your code constructs an `istream_iterator<string>` on the file, and by passing it, and the ending `istream_iterator<string>` value to the `vector`'s constructor, this effectively swallows the entire file, one whitespace-delimited word at a time, into the vector.

And by the time things get around to the `getline` loop, the entire file has already been read, and the loop does absolutely nothing. Your `getline` isn't really doing anything, with the current state of affairs.

Get rid of that stuff that involves `istream_iterator`s, completely, and simply let `getline` do the job it was intended for.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much, it's no wonder I was thrown off -- that was the example my instructor told us to use while also telling us to use getline. Fairly new to C++ so I would have never caught that, haha.